# ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (50,) for Tensor u'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(?, 10)'

Tags: linux, tensorflow

I'm a new guy in tensorflow,and I'm trying an experiment with my own .tfrecords files.Now I get something wrong in my code and I don't know what happend.Does anybody tell me how can I solve this problem

```
from  color_1 import read_and_decode, get_batch, get_test_batch
import cv2
import os
import time
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
batch_size=50
n_input=56*56*3
n_classes=10
def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape=shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def conv2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],  padding='SAME')
def max_pool_2x2(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],     padding='SAME')

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,56,56,3])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,n_classes])
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 56, 56, 3])


W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 3, 32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])


h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1)+b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])
h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

W_fc1 = weight_variable([14*14*64, 1024])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])

h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 14*14*64])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

keep_prob = tf.placeholder("float")
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])

y_conv = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2)

cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y * tf.log(y_conv))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

def run():
    image, label = read_and_decode('train.tfrecords')
    batch_image, batch_label = get_batch(image, label, batch_size,  crop_size=56)

    test_image, test_label = read_and_decode('val.tfrecords')
    test_images, test_labels = get_test_batch(test_image, test_label,  batch_size, crop_size=56)

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
        for i in range(20000):
            image_batch, label_batch = sess.run([batch_image, batch_label])

            if i%100 == 0:
                train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: image_batch, y:label_batch,keep_prob:1.0})
                print("step %d, training accuracy %g" % (i, train_accuracy))
                train_step.run(feed_dict={x:image_batch, y:label_batch,keep_prob:0.5})
        print("test accuracy %g" % accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
                    x:test_images, y:test_labels, keep_prob:1.0}))
        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)


if __name__=='__main__':
    run()
```

And the problem is just like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vrview/tensorflow/example/char/tfrecords/LeNet.py", line 130, in <module>
    run()
  File "/home/vrview/tensorflow/example/char/tfrecords/LeNet.py", line 120, in run
    train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: image_batch, y:label_batch,keep_prob:1.0})
  File "/home/vrview/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 581, in eval
    return _eval_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
  File "/home/vrview/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3797, in _eval_using_default_session
    return session.run(tensors, feed_dict)
  File "/home/vrview/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 767, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/vrview/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 944, in _run
    % (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (50,) for Tensor u'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(?, 10)'
```

train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: image_batch, y:label_batch,keep_prob:1.0})#bug is here

I don't know how should I do. Please tell me if you know. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like **label_batch** on line 120 is has the value of the labels and not the 1-hot encodings.  For example, it probably looks like a 1 dimensional array like this [1,3,4,0,6...] when instead it needs to be a 2 dimensional array of 1-hot encodings like this [ [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] , [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0] .... ].

You can use the [tf.one_hot function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/one_hot) to convert your **label_batch** into the needed form.  To do so change

```
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,n_classes])
```

to

```
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None])
y_one_hot = tf.one_hot( y , 10 )
```

and you'll have to change references to **y** to instead use **y_one_hot**

```
cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_one_hot * tf.log(y_conv))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv, 1), tf.argmax(y_one_hot, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
```

Cheers!

Comment: hello, I try what you said,and use tf.int32 instead of tf.float32 (if don't change ,it will be wrong) . But I get a new problem : # tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Failed to create session.Do you know how to solve it ? Thank you!

Comment: @Frank.Fan - ask for one problem to be solved per question.  I solved the original question but now you have changed your question.  If you have an error further along in the code it doesn't make my answer invalid.  I'd be happy to work on individual specific issues in separate posts.

Comment: just a note: instead of float32 in **y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None])**, I would specify int32.